# Here maps premium android Rotation not getting disabled

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to **disable** the **rotation** using **here maps premium** but I am not able to disable it. 
This is what I am trying to do. I am using **Gesture listener **, in that, i am overriding this method.

```
   @Override
        public boolean onRotateEvent(float v) {
            if(v >= 0){
                hereMapView.setRotation(0);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTwoFingerTapEvent(PointF pointF) {
            return super.onTwoFingerTapEvent(pointF);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRotateLocked() {
            super.onRotateLocked();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Return true in onRotate event.

public boolean onRotateEvent(float v) {
            if(v >= 0){
                hereMapView.setRotation(0);
            }
            return true;
        }

"True if consumed (which prevents the default map tilt-to-here behavior), false otherwise"

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/MapGesture.OnGestureListener.html#onRotateEvent-float-

Comment: Not working  somehow this is working                                                                     @Override
        public boolean onRotateEvent(float v) {
            hereMap.setOrientation(0);
            return true;
        }

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the SDK. When you setRotation(0) it forces a redraw of the screen so it is really battery and compute sub-optimal.